# How to clear cache memory in Blackberry?

Tags: caching, blackberry, memory-management

I am new in blackberry .I want to know how clear cache memory of my browser programatically in Blackberry?

Plz someone help me to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a bit vague question. Could you tell what do you mean under "cache memory"?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry you can´t access programatically to the browsers cache, so you have to do it Manually =(